# Clickable events no longer triggers once the element is covered by another element

Tags: html, css, dom

Simple example,

I have two divs

```
<div id="two"></div><div id="one"></div>
```

CSS is

```
#one{
     position: absolute;
 left: 3px;
 top: 3px;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: red;   
}

#two{
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: blue;
}
```

Event handler:

```
$("#two").click(function(){
alert("test")
})
```

since Two is covered by one because one comes after the two.

Two is no longer clickable.

Only way I know how to solve this is to reverse them.

```
<div id="one"></div><div id="two"></div>
```

But I will be dynamically generating those divisions for my applications. So the division has to come after.

Any ideas or suggestions around this problem

Here is the live example http://jsfiddle.net/Sca2c/4/

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS property `z-index`.

`z-index` defines the layers of the webpage, so an element with a `z-index` of `2` is above an element with a `z-index` of `1`.

Comment: Is there another way?
Binding z-index may not be an option for dynamically generated.